# add task using Google task api GAE login required?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-tasks-api

Well I have a directory `'/mytask'` I have logged in there and can see a list of all my tasks there and now I wanted to make another directory `'/addmytask'` where I wanted to add a new task. But when I tried following code:

service = build('tasks', 'v1')

```
class addtask(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       task = {
              'title': 'New Task',
              'notes': 'Please complete me',
              'due': '2010-10-15T12:00:00.000Z'
              }
       result = service.tasks().insert(tasklist='@default', body=task).execute()
```

It says "login required."

Documentation also says authentication required https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/insert#auth but I failed to figure out how to do it? Since I can see all my tasks in `'/mytask'` directory so I thought that they were refering to that login. But apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `@decorator.oauth_required` before my method.

I have added in my blog: http://sadaf2605.appspot.com/blog/python%20googole%20api%20Login%20required